# Create and use a function in Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am quite new on this platform and I am starting also to learn Google App script. I have issues a formula I am trying to insert in App script which is not working. I am trying to extract the week number, month and year and paste them automatically in their columns at each data entry (userform)

I used this formula but it doesn't work
Sorry to mix it up with a bit of french but here is the code:

```
// Boucle pour la semaine or Loop for the week

//var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base Données Production");

//ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod1, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A&+lastRow_Basedonprod1,Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
//ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod2, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A&+lastRow_Basedonprod2,Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
//ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod3, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A&+lastRow_Basedonprod3,Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
//ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod4, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A&+lastRow_Basedonprod4,Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
```

Basically what I am trying to do is every time I enter values in "Saisie production" tab, I am getting those values in a new sheet called "Base données Production". It's working fine except for the week, month and year which are in columns K,L,M.

Google sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F4-nzozPpmgP_QUtnUlbcnJPTgs-q7EmpPhuU2iUREk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to concatenate the value in your variables into the formula string. For example:

```js
var lastRow_Basedonprod1 = 1; // Assuming that the value is 1
var formula              = '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A' + lastRow_Basedonprod1 + ',Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")';

console.log( formula );
```

So your formula logic should look like this

```
ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod1, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'+ lastRow_Basedonprod1 + ',Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod2, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'+ lastRow_Basedonprod2 + ',Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod3, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'+ lastRow_Basedonprod3 + ',Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
ss1.getRange( lastRow_Basedonprod4, 11 ).setFormula( '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'+ lastRow_Basedonprod4 + ',Utilitaire!$C$21:$H$386,4),"")' );
```

Comment: Bonus points for including the snippet :)